# Remove javascript:ShowExternal in href

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to remove **javascript:ShowExternal** from href attribute `javascript:ShowExternal('http://www.hhgsurvey.com/CustomerSurveyReport.aspx?SurveyID=M3B9A8')`,i want get only URL from href attribute so how do i that.

```
<a style="color:Blue;text-decoration:underline;" href="javascript:ShowExternal('http://www.hhgsurvey.com/CustomerSurveyReport.aspx?SurveyID=M3A779')" class="cmn" id="ctl00_cntPlcHld1_lstvwSurveys_ctrl14_hlsurvey">View</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

```
var temp = "javascript:ShowExternal('http://www.hhgsurvey.com/CustomerSurveyReport.aspx?SurveyID=M3B9A8')";
trm = /\((.*)\)/i;
console.log(temp.match(trm)[1]);
```

It will give you output:

```
'http://www.hhgsurvey.com/CustomerSurveyReport.aspx?SurveyID=M3B9A8'
```

Answer (score 1):

on click of view link you can get the URL

```
 $(document.body).on('click',"a",function(event){ 
    var temp =$(this).attr("href") ;
trm = /\((.*)\)/i;
console.log(temp.match(trm)[1]);
});
```

output will be:

'http://www.hhgsurvey.com/CustomerSurveyReport.aspx?SurveyID=M3A779'

Comment: Follow this solution its more precise

Answer (score 1):

Try like this [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/tnvjmcoL/)

```
var text = $('a').attr('href');
var result = text.replace('javascript:ShowExternal(','');

console.log(result.slice(0,-1));
```